# Keep current_user on registration page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a page called "comment". On that comment page/form, I have the comments form fields and a user registration form fields. What happens is, after a new user fills out all fields and hit submit, it creates a new user which post a comment on the fly.

I wish to re-use that same page for new comments. If that user is logged in, devise redirects the user saying "currently logged in blah blah". I want the user to still be able to access that page (while logged in). I'll only hide the registration fields. Is this possible with Devise?

**The comment controller looks something like:**

```
class CommentsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 ...

 def new
  ...
 end

end
```

**Routes:**

```
devise_scope :user do get "/comments/new" => "comments#new" end
```

**Comment form(new):**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: comment_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

  # hidden fields which passed as params for the comments
  # div with registration fields that uses f.email etc

  # divs for the comment fields that uses text_area_tag


<% end %>
```

**Registration controller:**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

 def create
  super do |resource|
   # the passed in params which assign as variables
   resource.save!(Comment.create(...) #params vars goes here etc
  end
 end
end
```

Do I really have to create another controller for comments?

Comment: Hopefully I'm understanding correctly but could you not wrap the registration form in a conditional? So if not the current_user show form else hide it?

Comment: @Richlewis well not really, the resource form is wrapped around the comments so that is not likely. But if a separate controller is best then that's ok. I thought there was a simpler way out ;) Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Sylar, have you tried to make a partial page that contains the registration page. After submit of comment and redirect to new page, you can render the registration page again. As well as using session for checking "currently logged in...."